# Цикл for с помощью Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть метод, пытаюсь переделать цикл for через Stream API, но не выходит((( Ребята подскажите пожалуйста можно ли тут что-то придумать и сделать через Stream, много чего перепробовал но пока не нашёл решение, интересно что среда разработки, как вариант, подсказывает что лучше использовать цикл)))

```
public LocalDate getDate() {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1);
        List<Order> sortOrder = orderDao.sortedByDate();

        for (Order order : sortOrder) {
            LocalDate endDate = order.getEndDate();
            if (endDate.isEqual(date)){
                date = date.plusDays(1);
            }
        }
        return date;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного модифицирую предыдущий ответ:

```
        final LocalDate date = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1);
        List<Order> sortOrder = orderDao.sortedByDate();

        long numberOfDaysToAdd = sortOrder.stream()
                .map(Order::getEndDate)
                .filter(new Predicate<>() {

                    int сount;
                    boolean result;

                    @Override
                    public boolean test(LocalDate endDate) {
                        if(result = endDate.equals(date.plusDays(сount))) сount++;
                        return result;
                    }
                })
                .count();

        return date.plusDays(numberOfDaysToAdd);
```

Заменяем лямбду в методе filter на анонимный класс, который будет хранить количество успешных сравнений. Соответственно сравнивать будем с учётом этого количества (увеличивая исходный объект data на сохранённое раньше количество успешных сравнений).

И да, с параллельными стримами лучше не использовать)

Comment: Интересное решение

Comment: @Serodv Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если хочется стримом:

```
    public LocalDate getDate2() {
    final LocalDate date = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1);
    List<Order> sortOrder = orderDao.sortedByDate();
    
    long numberOfDaysToAdd = sortOrder.stream()
            .map(Order::getEndDate)
            .filter(endDate -> endDate.isEqual(date))
            .count();
    return date.plusDays(numberOfDaysToAdd);
  }
```

Обратите внимание, что `plusDays` всегда возвращает новый объект `LocalDate`, а у Вас он в цикле. Правильнее будет сперва посчитать, сколько дней нужно прибавить.

Comment: У автора несколько иная логика - он модифицирует в цикле объект date и на следующей итерации сравнивает содержимое списка с уже модифицированным date

Comment: Точно, не заметил, тогда мой вариант отпадает. В алгоритме мутируется date, а в лямбдах мы можем использовать только effectively final переменные, поэтому не вижу иной возможности переписать это в стрим, разве только пересмотреть сам алгоритм решения задачи)

Comment: Да, по логике у меня изменяется объект date в теле цикла и далее следующий элемент списка <Order> сравнивается c уже изменённым объектом date.

Answer (score 0):

Стримы здесь не совсем подходят, так как здесь имеется изменчивое состояние `date` и соответственно придётся использовать некий контейнер, чтобы `date` *выглядело **условно финальной (effectively final)*** для стрима.

При этом модифицировать значение `date` нужно будет на этапе фильтра, так что "решение" на стриме *может* выглядеть так:

```java
public LocalDate getDate() {
    AtomicReference<LocalDate> ld = new AtomicReference<>(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1));
        
    return orderDao.sortedByDate()
        .stream()               // Stream<Order>
        .map(Order::getEndDate) // Stream<LocalDate>
        .filter(d -> {
            boolean r = d.isEqual(ld.get());
            if (r) {
                // простое присваивание ld = d.plusDays(1); запрещено
                ld.set(d.plusDays(1)); 
            }
            return r;
        })
        .max(Comparator.naturalOrder()) // Optional<LocalDate>
        .map(d -> d.plusDays(1))
        .orElse(ld.get());
}
```

Очевидно, что в данном случае решение с использованием Stream API не выглядит лучшим образом, и к тому же стрим должен быть по умолчанию упорядоченным.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Тоже склоняюсь к мысли что лучше в данной ситуации не использовать Stream API, а лучше оставить цикл.